# Azure Function: Can't check memory usage of instances

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

[image]

I'm using Azure Function App, in Application Insight-performance, I'm able to see the CPU usage of each instance but not memory or IO rate...

What could be the reason? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the issue by watching the metrics, logs of the Azure Function App (Python Stack) as it is showing most of the metrics like Server Requests, Response, Success and Failure logs except the Memory working set and few.

[image]

But as per this [MSFT documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/monitor-metrics?tabs=portal#functions-specific-metrics) I came to know that

> Memory data isn't a metric currently available through Azure Monitor. However, if you want to optimize the memory usage of your app, can use the performance counter data collected by Application Insights. This metric isn't currently supported for Premium and Dedicated (App Service) plans running on Linux.

Refer [Azure Monitor Performance counter metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/performance-counters) to learn more Information.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like we might still be able to view memory usage using app insights. The following query looks at the performance counters.

```
performanceCounters
| where cloud_RoleName == '<service name>'
| where counter in('Private Bytes', 'Virtual Bytes')
| summarize avg(value) by bin(timestamp, 15m), counter
| order by timestamp desc
| render timechart
```

See [Performance counters in log analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/performance-counters#performance-counters-in-log-analytics)